# Lightdm service - contradictory results for `status` command

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, services, lightdm

When I run in my gnome-terminal:

```
service lightdm status
```

everything looks OK and it is as expected:

```
lightdm start/running, process 1221
```

But when I run:

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | grep lightdm
```

the output is:

```
 [ ? ]  lightdm
```

which, because of `?`, AFAIK means that the lightdm service doesn't have a `status` command.

Now I want to understand from where came these contradictory results? Is this a bug?

Comment: Seems odd. I get `[ + ]  lightdm` as expected. Probably nothing to worry about - if there was a real problem then you likely wouldn't be able to log in. What distro are you using?

Comment: @Graeme I'm not worrying. I just want to understand how is this possible. I get the same results in Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just seems to be a bug in the `service` script. The behaviour is different for `--status-all` than for a single process. For a single process, `service` just uses `exec` to hand over to the init script itself (in this case `/etc/init.d/lightdm`). Here is the relevant snippet:

```
if [ -x "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ]; then
   exec env -i LANG="$LANG" PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "$SERVICEDIR/$SERVICE" ${ACTION} ${OPTIONS}
```

For `--status-all` it tries to parse the output of the `init.d` script itself. Downloading the `sysvinit-tools` package for Ubuntu 13.10 and comparing to my version (Debian Jessie), you can see that there has been a change made to that part of the code (most likely to fix this exactly this kind of bug). Compare this (Ubuntu 13.10) snippet (I have marked the changed lines with `#<<<`:

```
if [ -z "${SERVICE}" -a $# -eq 1 -a "${1}" = "--status-all" ]; then
   cd ${SERVICEDIR}
   for SERVICE in * ; do
     case "${SERVICE}" in
       functions | halt | killall | single| linuxconf| kudzu)
           ;;
       *)
         if ! is_ignored_file "${SERVICE}" \
 && [ -x "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ]; then
                 if ! grep -qs "\(^\|\W\)status)" "$SERVICE"; then     #<<<
                   #printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[?]" "$SERVICE:" "unknown" 1>&2
                   echo " [ ? ]  $SERVICE" 1>&2
                   continue
```

And

```
if [ -z "${SERVICE}" -a $# -eq 1 -a "${1}" = "--status-all" ]; then
   cd ${SERVICEDIR}
   for SERVICE in * ; do
     case "${SERVICE}" in
       functions | halt | killall | single| linuxconf| kudzu)
           ;;
       *)
         if ! is_ignored_file "${SERVICE}" \
 && [ -x "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ]; then
                 out=$(env -i LANG="$LANG" PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "$SERVICEDIR/$SERVICE" status 2>&1)  #<<<
                 retval=$?                                                   #<<<
                 if echo "$out" | egrep -iq "usage:"; then                   #<<<
                   #printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[?]" "$SERVICE:" "unknown" 1>&2
                   echo " [ ? ]  $SERVICE" 1>&2
                   continue
```

Comment: So... it's a bug in `/usr/sbin/service` script!

Comment: @Radu, ok, there are actually a few different things that `service` will do depending on how the system is set up. For me it still essentially runs `/etc/init.d/lightdm status`, as per the updated first snippet. You can find out what it is really up to by doing `sh -x /usr/sbin/service lightdm status`. The last line before the status output will show you how it is determining the status.

Comment: Although there is only one option for `--status-all`, no matter how the system is set up.